# Django can use session I set, but can not see that in web browser's inspector

Tags: django, cookies, mongoengine

I'm using `Django` with `MongoDB` as a back-end database.

In `settings.py` I already set these codes:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'

'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

'django.contrib.sessions',
```

And in my `view/user.py` (only part of the code)

```
                 if user.password == password:
                    #add session information
                    if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                        returnmsg = "COOKIE OK"
                    else:
                        returnmsg = "COOKIE ERR"
                    response = HttpResponse(returnmsg)
                    response.set_cookie("username", username)
                    request.session['username'] = username
                    user.log.append(UserLog(time=datetime.now(), ip=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], login=True))
                    user.save()
                    return response
```

When I run my site, I could login by this function and other functions which need verify my session setting could read `username` from `response.session`.

But the returnmsg is `COOKIE ERR`, and when I use Web Inspector of Safari, I can see no session or cookie here.

Where does Django store it session data? Should it be an encoded cookie on client's computer? If it does not store on my client's computer, why `Django` still could get that?
And in my code I also tried just set a cookie directly, it still does not work.

Is there something wrong about `MongoEngine`? Did I use it in the wrong way?

Comment: I **do** hope that you're not storing passwords as plain text, as seems to be implied by this code.

Comment: Just a simple test of that. I do make a MD5 encode for password in the context.

Answer (score 1):

You should set a test cookie first with `set_test_cookie()`, and then on a subsequent request check for it with `test_cookie_worked()`.

The function doesn't test if cookies work, it checks specifically if the test cookie was successfully set - which has a consequence of checking if cookies work.

Unless you use `set_test_cookie()`, `test_cookie_worked()` will always fail.

Comment: Thanks, when I try this, it gives me lots of error messages. It tells me a `TemplateDoesNotExist`, but I do not use any template.

Comment: Update: It tells me that my firefox and safari do not support cookie. But I actually do not disable it.